# Python Regex Finding a Match That Starts Inside Previous match

Tags: python, regex, genetics, rosalind

I'm looking to find the index for all substrings in a string in python. My current regex code can't find a match that has it's start in a previous match.

I have a string: `s = r'GATATATGCATATACTT'` and a subtring `t = r'ATAT'`. There should be matches at index 1, 3, and 9. Using the following code only shows matches at index 1 and 9 because index 3 is within the first match. How do I get all matches to appear?

Thanks so much!

```
import re

s= 'GATATATGCATATACTT'
t = r'ATAT'

pattern = re.compile(t)

[print(i) for i in pattern.finditer(s)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have overlapping matches, you need to use a capturing group inside a lookahead as: `(?=(YOUEXPR))`

```
import re

s= 'GATATATGCATATACTT'
t = r'(?=(ATAT))'

pattern = re.compile(t)

[print(i) for i in pattern.finditer(s)]
```

Output:

```
<re.Match object; span=(1, 1), match=''>
<re.Match object; span=(3, 3), match=''>
<re.Match object; span=(9, 9), match=''>
```

Or:

```
[print(i.start()) for i in pattern.finditer(s)]
```

Output:

```
1
3
9
```

Or:

```
import re

s= 'GATATATGCATATACTT'
t = 'ATAT'

pattern = re.compile(f'(?=({t}))')

print ([(i.start(), s[i.start():i.start()+len(t)]) for i in pattern.finditer(s)])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'ATAT'), (3, 'ATAT'), (9, 'ATAT')]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly. I still don't totally understand the look around part of regex, but I will read more now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the location, your best bet is [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re 

s = r'GATATATGCATATACTT'
t = r'ATAT'

>>> [m for m in re.finditer(rf'(?={t})', s)]
[<re.Match object; span=(1, 1), match=''>, <re.Match object; span=(3, 3), match=''>, <re.Match object; span=(9, 9), match=''>]
```

With the returned [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), you can get the start index:

```
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(rf'(?={t})', s)]
[1, 3, 9]
```

You can also find overlapping sub string in pure Python:

```
def find_overlaps(s, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = s.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1: return
        yield start
        start += 1

>>> list(find_overlaps(s,t))
[1, 3, 9]
```